# Angular and <code> HTML

Tags: angular

I wonder how can I achieve my goal in a clean way. Here's the problem: 
In my angular view I want to have the following code block to explain to my customers how to set up an embeded plugin

In angular(5.X) view

```
  <code>
    <script src="https://plugin.example.io"></script>
    <script>
      const myBot = new Bot({{ uid }}) // Here I want to inject the `uid` var coming from my angular controller
    </script>
  </code>
```

Of course I don't want the code to be interpreted but just displayed as a code block should do.

Problem is that angular sanitizes view before rendering it to avoid security issues. However I thought of `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` but problem is how to inject my `uid` and remains the code clean ?

Is there any known directive that can make the trick ?

Thank you.

Comment: Rather than use literal carets, `<` you can use the html entity `&lt;`: `&lt;script src=""&gt;&lt;/script&gt;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and encode special HTML entities like :

`&lt;script src="https://plugin.example.io"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;`

will be rendered in the view as :

`<script src="https://plugin.example.io"></script>`

but not interpreted.

**Edit**

I guess even just the first characted should do the trick and prevent the whole thing from being interpreted.

`&lt;script src="https://plugin.example.io"></script>`

Comment: Not the most beautiful thing I ever done but works like a charm

Comment: A man's gotta do what he's gotta do :) (Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem)